# Как реализовать камеру в pygame с использованием tiled map editor?

Tags: python-3.x, разработка-игр, pygame

подскажите алгоритм как используя tiled map editor, создать камеру, которая следит за игроком. В идеале, чтобы камера перемещалась лишь в том случае, если игрок дошёл до какого-то места на экране (допустим, по 50 пикселей от угла).

Текущий код:

```
import pygame, sys
from random import randint
from pytmx.util_pygame import load_pygame


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,group):
        super().__init__(group)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('graphics/player.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.speed = 5

    def input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.direction.y = -1
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.direction.y = 1
        else:
            self.direction.y = 0

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.direction.x = 1
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.direction.x = -1
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0

    def update(self):
        self.input()
        self.rect.center += self.direction * self.speed

class CameraGroup(pygame.sprite.Group):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.display_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()

        # camera offset 
        self.offset = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.half_w = self.display_surface.get_size()[0] // 2
        self.half_h = self.display_surface.get_size()[1] // 2

        # box setup
        self.camera_borders = {'left': 200, 'right': 200, 'top': 100, 'bottom': 100}
        l = self.camera_borders['left']
        t = self.camera_borders['top']
        w = self.display_surface.get_size()[0]  - (self.camera_borders['left'] + self.camera_borders['right'])
        h = self.display_surface.get_size()[1]  - (self.camera_borders['top'] + self.camera_borders['bottom'])
        self.camera_rect = pygame.Rect(l,t,w,h)

        # ground
        self.ground_surf = pygame.image.load('graphics/ground.png').convert_alpha()
        self.ground_rect = self.ground_surf.get_rect(topleft = (0,0))



        # camera speed
        self.keyboard_speed = 5
        self.mouse_speed = 0.2

        # zoom 
        self.zoom_scale = 1
        self.internal_surf_size = (2500,2500)
        self.internal_surf = pygame.Surface(self.internal_surf_size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.internal_rect = self.internal_surf.get_rect(center = (self.half_w,self.half_h))
        self.internal_surface_size_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(self.internal_surf_size)
        self.internal_offset = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.internal_offset.x = self.internal_surf_size[0] // 2 - self.half_w
        self.internal_offset.y = self.internal_surf_size[1] // 2 - self.half_h

    def center_target_camera(self,target):
        self.offset.x = target.rect.centerx - self.half_w
        self.offset.y = target.rect.centery - self.half_h

    def box_target_camera(self,target):

        if target.rect.left < self.camera_rect.left:
            self.camera_rect.left = target.rect.left
        if target.rect.right > self.camera_rect.right:
            self.camera_rect.right = target.rect.right
        if target.rect.top < self.camera_rect.top:
            self.camera_rect.top = target.rect.top
        if target.rect.bottom > self.camera_rect.bottom:
            self.camera_rect.bottom = target.rect.bottom

        self.offset.x = self.camera_rect.left - self.camera_borders['left']
        self.offset.y = self.camera_rect.top - self.camera_borders['top']

    def keyboard_control(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]: self.camera_rect.x -= self.keyboard_speed
        if keys[pygame.K_d]: self.camera_rect.x += self.keyboard_speed
        if keys[pygame.K_w]: self.camera_rect.y -= self.keyboard_speed
        if keys[pygame.K_s]: self.camera_rect.y += self.keyboard_speed

        self.offset.x = self.camera_rect.left - self.camera_borders['left']
        self.offset.y = self.camera_rect.top - self.camera_borders['top']

    def mouse_control(self):
        mouse = pygame.math.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        mouse_offset_vector = pygame.math.Vector2()

        left_border = self.camera_borders['left']
        top_border = self.camera_borders['top']
        right_border = self.display_surface.get_size()[0] - self.camera_borders['right']
        bottom_border = self.display_surface.get_size()[1] - self.camera_borders['bottom']

        if top_border < mouse.y < bottom_border:
            if mouse.x < left_border:
                mouse_offset_vector.x = mouse.x - left_border
                pygame.mouse.set_pos((left_border,mouse.y))
            if mouse.x > right_border:
                mouse_offset_vector.x = mouse.x - right_border
                pygame.mouse.set_pos((right_border,mouse.y))
        elif mouse.y < top_border:
            if mouse.x < left_border:
                mouse_offset_vector = mouse - pygame.math.Vector2(left_border,top_border)
                pygame.mouse.set_pos((left_border,top_border))
            if mouse.x > right_border:
                mouse_offset_vector = mouse - pygame.math.Vector2(right_border,top_border)
                pygame.mouse.set_pos((right_border,top_border))
        elif mouse.y > bottom_border:
            if mouse.x < left_border:
                mouse_offset_vector = mouse - pygame.math.Vector2(left_border,bottom_border)
                pygame.mouse.set_pos((left_border,bottom_border))
            if mouse.x > right_border:
                mouse_offset_vector = mouse - pygame.math.Vector2(right_border,bottom_border)
                pygame.mouse.set_pos((right_border,bottom_border))

        if left_border < mouse.x < right_border:
            if mouse.y < top_border:
                mouse_offset_vector.y = mouse.y - top_border
                pygame.mouse.set_pos((mouse.x,top_border))
            if mouse.y > bottom_border:
                mouse_offset_vector.y = mouse.y - bottom_border
                pygame.mouse.set_pos((mouse.x,bottom_border))

        self.offset += mouse_offset_vector * self.mouse_speed

    def zoom_keyboard_control(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_q]:
            self.zoom_scale += 0.1
        if keys[pygame.K_e]:
            self.zoom_scale -= 0.1

    def custom_draw(self,player):
        
        # self.center_target_camera(player)
        self.box_target_camera(player)
        # self.keyboard_control()
        # self.mouse_control()
        # self.zoom_keyboard_control()


        # ground 
        """ground_offset = self.ground_rect.topleft - self.offset + self.internal_offset
        self.internal_surf.blit(self.ground_surf,ground_offset)"""

        # active elements
        for sprite in sorted(self.sprites(),key = lambda sprite: sprite.rect.centery):
            offset_pos = sprite.rect.topleft - self.offset + self.internal_offset
            self.internal_surf.blit(sprite.image,offset_pos)

        scaled_surf = pygame.transform.scale(self.internal_surf,self.internal_surface_size_vector * self.zoom_scale)
        scaled_rect = scaled_surf.get_rect(center = (self.half_w,self.half_h))

        self.display_surface.blit(scaled_surf,scaled_rect)

class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, surf, groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = surf
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.event.set_grab(True)

tmx_data = load_pygame('map_v2.0/map_new/map.tmx')
sprite_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

for layer in tmx_data.visible_layers:
            # if layer.name in ('Floor', 'Plants and rocks', 'Pipes')
    if hasattr(layer, 'data'):
        for x, y, surf in layer.tiles():
            pos = (x * 64, y * 64)
            Tile(pos=pos, surf=surf, groups=sprite_group)




# setup 
camera_group = CameraGroup()
player = Player((640,360),camera_group)



while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEWHEEL:
            camera_group.zoom_scale += event.y * 0.03

    screen.fill('#71ddee')
    sprite_group.draw(screen)

    camera_group.update()
    camera_group.custom_draw(player)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```